# How are two-dose vaccine schedules developed?

Tags: covid-19, virus, vaccination, clinical-study

How are vaccination schedules determined for multi-dose vaccines? That is, are several different schedules tested in an early-phase trial? Or do the developers of a vaccine choose a schedule (based on results from similar vaccines, computer models, etc) before anyone is ever injected?

[This question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25759/covid-19-vaccination-second-doses-why-two-doses-and-why-the-specified-interval) asks about the medical/biological reasons that two-dose COVID-19 vaccines are taken 21/28 days apart, but I'm interested in the development side.

Comment: Relevant: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25759